# Laravel; optimal database, model relationships and Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a scenario where a vendor can hold workshops for users.

Every workshop needs to have an availability (this is date based - for example the workshops could be available on the 22nd and/or the 27th and so on).

A workshop can have multiple availabilities - that is , the same workshop can run on many days.

In order for a user to participate in a workshop they need a booking - that is, they choose which availability date they will attend.

In order to make a booking they need to have a transaction.

One transaction can be for many bookings - as in a user can pay for multiple workshops with one transaction.

A user can only have booking per workshop.

Currently I have the following:

Availability model has:

```
    public function workshops()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Workshop::class, 'workshop_id');
    }

    public function bookings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Booking::class, 'availabilities_id');
    }
```

Bookings model has:

```
    public function vendorAvailability()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Availability::class, 'id', 'availabilities_id');
    }

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Transaction::class, 'id', 'transaction_id');
    }
```

Transactions model has:

```
public function bookings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Booking::class, 'id', 'transaction_id');
}
```

The table structures look like this:

```
`workshops`
  `id` 
  `vendor_id` 
  `workshop_cost`
  `workshop_name`

`availabilities` 
  `id` 
  `vendor_id`
  `workshop_id`
  `name`
  `start_time`

`bookings`
  `id` 
  `user_id`
  `availabilities_id`
  `transaction_id`
  `workshop_id` 
  `is_completed_vendor`
  `is_completed_user`     

`transactions`
  `id`
  `user_id`
  `vendor_id`
  `workshop_id`
  `status`
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
$ListWorkshops = Availability::with(['workshops','bookings'])
    ->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)
    ->get();
```

I want to be able to display information on a vendor's dashboard. Specifically I am looking to show a list that has:

```
Workshops
        Availabilities
            Bookings per availabilities - is_completed_vendor, is_completed_user - status
```

Where "is_completed_vendor, is_completed_user" are boolean fields on the bookings table that the vendor and user would mark as 'y' respectively once the workshop is complete. Status is from the transaction table and would also be updated once the workshop is complete.

So an example list could look like this:

```
Explaining code to beginners
    May, 21
            Violet Dickinson - y, y - complete
            Savanna Avalos - y, y - complete
            Luc Stephens - y, y - complete
    May, 28                         
            Bryan Nicholls - y, y - complete
            Gareth Patterson - y, y - complete
                
        
More code for endusers
    July, 21
        Ricky Molloy - n, n - pending
        Blanche Sparks - n, n - pending
    July, 28
        Raphael Trejo - n, n - pending
        Tina Lopez - n, n - pending
        Susan Wallace - n, n - pending
```

**EDIT:**

In the desired list above I have added in the Status field from the transaction table. This is related through the bookings table but I am not getting that returned. I do have a foreign key on the bookings table:

```
  CONSTRAINT `bookings_transaction_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_id`) REFERENCES `transactions` (`id`)
```

However when I dd($ListWorkshops) that status is not showing, that is there are no relations shown off the bookings result

```
  0 => App\Availability {#2753 ▼
       #table: "availabilities"
       #attributes: array:16 [▶]
       #relations: array:2 [▼
         "workshops" => App\Workshop {#2749 ▶}
         "bookings" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2575 ▼
           #items: array:2 [▼
             0 => App\Booking {#2744 ▼
               #table: "bookings"
               #attributes: array:17 [▶]
               #relations: [] --> I need transaction details to show here
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
```

If I do this:

```
$ListWorkshops = Availability::with(['workshops','bookings' ])
->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)
->where('availabilities.workshop_id', '>', '0')
->join('bookings', 'bookings.availabilities_id', '=', 'availabilities.id')
->join('transactions', 'bookings.transaction_id', '=', 'transactions.id')
->get();
```

I can then get the transaction status but cannot iterate through bookings as that is empty, and therefore is obviously not correct for what I need.

So my question is - what do I need to do in order to bring in the Status field from the transaction table so that I can iterate through bookings and return the transaction status?

Comment: It looks good. Have you looked at the querys Eloquent is building to get all the data?. I'd also pay attention to indexes for an optimal performance

Comment: Thanks, I have made some edits to the question. There is something I am missing in creating these relationships. I have looked at the Eloquent queries but must be missing something logically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to eager load the relationship - added 'bookings.transactions' as below:

```
$ListWorkshops = Availability::with(['workshops','bookings','bookings.transactions'])
->where('vendor_id', $vendor_id)
->where('availabilities.workshop_id', '>', '0')
->get();
```